# How to use YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: android, youtube

My App has access to YouTube Data API v3, but I can't use live broadcasting function properly.Is it my parameter configuration error?

My code still works well in January, but from a while ago I found that I couldn't see it on YouTube in real time when I was broadcasting live. It took me an hour or two to see my live video.Is there any change in the Google platform?

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get a list of up to 10 files.
        List<String> channelInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        ChannelListResponse result = mService.channels().list("snippet,contentDetails,statistics")
                .setForUsername("GoogleDevelopers")
                .execute();
        List<Channel> channels = result.getItems();
        if (channels != null) {
            Channel channel = channels.get(0);
            channelInfo.add("This channel's ID is " + channel.getId() + ". " +
                    "Its title is '" + channel.getSnippet().getTitle() + ", " +
                    "and it has " + channel.getStatistics().getViewCount() + " views.");
        }
        LiveBroadcastSnippet broadcastSnippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
        broadcastSnippet.setTitle("GoLive Cam Test");


        String format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));//指定时区
        String dateStr  = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = null;
        long time1 = 0L;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
            time1 = date.getTime()+1*60*1000;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis()+3*60*1000;
        broadcastSnippet.setPublishedAt(new DateTime(time1));

        broadcastSnippet.setActualStartTime(new DateTime(time));
        broadcastSnippet.setScheduledStartTime(new DateTime(time));


        LiveBroadcastStatus status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");

        LiveBroadcast broadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
        broadcast.setKind("youtube#liveBroadcast");
        broadcast.setSnippet(broadcastSnippet);
        broadcast.setStatus(status);

        LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = new LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
        contentDetails.setProjection("360");
        broadcast.setContentDetails(contentDetails);

        YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Insert liveBroadcastInsert =
                mService.liveBroadcasts().insert("snippet,status,contentDetails", broadcast);
        broadcast = liveBroadcastInsert.execute();

        LiveStreamSnippet streamSnippet = new LiveStreamSnippet();
        streamSnippet.setTitle("GoLive Cam Test");

        IngestionInfo ingestionInfo = new IngestionInfo();
        ingestionInfo.setStreamName("GoLive Stream");

        ingestionInfo.setIngestionAddress("rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2");

        CdnSettings cdnSettings = new CdnSettings();
        cdnSettings.setIngestionInfo(ingestionInfo);

        cdnSettings.setResolution("720P");
        cdnSettings.setFrameRate("30fps");
        cdnSettings.setIngestionType("rtmp");

        LiveStream stream = new LiveStream();
        stream.setKind("youtube#liveStream");
        stream.setSnippet(streamSnippet);
        stream.setCdn(cdnSettings);

        YouTube.LiveStreams.Insert liveStreamInsert =
                mService.liveStreams().insert("snippet,cdn", stream);
        stream = liveStreamInsert.execute();
       push_addr = stream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getIngestionAddress() + "/" + stream.getCdn()
                .getIngestionInfo().getStreamName();

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Bind liveBroadcastBind =
                mService.liveBroadcasts().bind(broadcast.getId(), "id,contentDetails");
        liveBroadcastBind.setStreamId(stream.getId());
        broadcast = liveBroadcastBind.execute();
        String share_addr = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + broadcast.getId();

        YouTube.LiveStreams.List
                            liveStreamRequest = mService.liveStreams()
                .list("id,status")
                .setId(broadcast.getContentDetails()
                        .getBoundStreamId());
        LiveStreamListResponse returnedList = liveStreamRequest.execute();
        List<LiveStream> liveStreams = returnedList.getItems();
        if (liveStreams != null && liveStreams.size() > 0) {
            LiveStream liveStream = liveStreams.get(0);
            if (liveStream != null)
                while (!liveStream.getStatus().getStreamStatus().equals("active")) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        returnedList = liveStreamRequest.execute();
                        liveStreams = returnedList.getItems();
                        liveStream = liveStreams.get(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            final YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Transition broadCastTestingRequest = mService
                    .liveBroadcasts().transition("testing",
                            broadcast.getId(), "id,snippet,contentDetails,status");
            broadcast = broadCastTestingRequest.execute();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

            YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.List liveBroadRequest = mService.liveBroadcasts().list("id,status");
            liveBroadRequest.setBroadcastStatus("all");

            LiveBroadcastListResponse liveBroadcastResponse = liveBroadRequest.execute();
            List<LiveBroadcast> returnedList1 = liveBroadcastResponse.getItems();
            if (returnedList1 != null && returnedList1.size() > 0) {
                LiveBroadcast liveBroadcastReq = returnedList1.get(0);
                if (liveBroadcastReq != null)
                    while (!liveBroadcastReq.getStatus().getLifeCycleStatus().equals("testing")) {
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            AppLog.d("Error","publish broadcast - getLifeCycleStatus: " + liveBroadcastReq.getStatus().getLifeCycleStatus());
                            liveBroadcastResponse = liveBroadRequest.execute();
                            returnedList1 = liveBroadcastResponse.getItems();
                            liveBroadcastReq = returnedList1.get(0);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Transition transitionRequest = mService.liveBroadcasts().transition("live", broadcast.getId(), "status");
                broadcast = transitionRequest.execute();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    Message message  = new Message();
                    message.what = 2 ;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("share_address",share_addr);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return channelInfo;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mi7A.png)

Like the picture I posted above, it takes an hour or two to see my live video.

Comment: Can you add in your question the description of the error(s) *if any*?

Comment: There is no error output, but the live picture is not real-time, it needs to wait an hour or two to see the live picture. As you can see from your YouTube account, my live page is always on the waiting list.